# how to find single child node within xml

Tags: c#, xml

```
<bookstore>
    <book>
         <title>bob</title>
         <author>fred</author>
     </book>
...
```

Using the C# `XmlTextReader`, how do I print out the author, only when the book title is `bob`?

Comment: Why can't you use Linq to Xml ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlDocument

1. use getElementByTagName for "book"
2. Iterate through elements and use condition to get the correct title which contains "BOB"
3. Get the author value from that parent book node.

Hope you understood what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to find the node:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("yourfile.xml"); 
string path = "/bookstore/book[title='bob']"; // find the book node only when the book title is bob
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(path); // get the book node
string author = node.SelectSingleNode("author").InnerText; // find the author node, return its inner text
```

If the value of book title is not unique, you may use XmlDocument.SelectNodes instead.

```
XmlNodeList books = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(path); // find all books whose title is bob 
foreadh(XmlNode book in books)
{
    string author = node.SelectSingleNode("author").InnerText;
    ...
}
```